# Accessing the DataGridView Control on setting Property for Custom DataGridViewColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

can some help me on how can I find the `DataGridView` control in the property `setter` of a Custom `DataGridViewColumn`. My code below is returning null. I want to get the parent `DataGridView` of my custom column.

```
public class CustomComboBoxColumn : DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
{
  public string SomeProperty
  {
    get { return _SomeProperty; }
    set
        {
          _SomeProperty = value;
          CustomDataGridView dgv = this.DataGridView;  //this one is returning null

        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is your Datagridview id called "DataGridView"?
That appears like you're trying to set dgv returns to a type unless that is the objects ID. So if it is the id then is it possible it's in a template or panel of some kind?

Comment: I edited my question. The error is that the this.DataGridView; is always returning null. So is there a way to get the parent datagridview of a custom column?

Comment: When is this property set? Is the Column already added to the DGV's `Columns` collection? If done correctly, that property will return the DGV's it belongs to. Btw, use `var dgv = this.DataGridView;`.

Answer (score 0):

The [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.datagridview?view=netframework-4.8) (in WinForms - judging from the post tag) is a property of the [DataGridViewColumnCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection?view=netframework-4.8)  - and not that of the [DataGridViewColumn Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn?view=netframework-4.8)  So since you are deriving this class from the 
DataGridViewColumn derived class, you would have to make this property trickle down from the custom column collection to each of the custom columns added to it, perhaps you can make the collection itself accessible in each added column by implementing a Column.Collection custom property, and initializing it each time you add a column to a Collection. Then you can use inside your  CustomComboBoxColumn class something alike this: 
`CustomDataGridView dgv = this.CustomComboBoxColumnCollection.DataGridView;`
.

> Alternativelly, consider to do what you were intending to do in CustomComboBoxColumn class in the collection that contains it instead. In the Collection you can access the `CustomComboBoxColumnCollection.DataGridView` property, and subsequently set the needed results at the time that you are adding the new Columns into the Collection.

Do what feels more natural to you and requires less coding :)